# How to install Ubuntu 20.10 on the new XPS 17 (9700)?

Tags: nvidia, sound, xps, multi-touch, 20.10

I saw a few posts online of people having some issues setting up the new XPS 17 as a Linux machine so I thought I'd share my journey here in case it'd be of anyone's interest. I've been using Ubuntu as my only OS for roughly 2 years now, so I'm somewhat knowledgeable about Linux itself but as far as drivers and kernel stuff goes I'm definitely a beginner so I hold very few credits apart from copying what other people did.

From my Github page: https://github.com/letourneaualex/xps17-9700_Ubuntu2010.git

I might add some shell script eventually to automate some of the steps, just need some of that ever elusive spare time!

Laptop specs:
Dell XPS 17 (9700)
64Gb RAM
i7 10875H
1Tb SSD
RTX 2060
4k screen

Install:
Ubuntu 20.10 single-boot- kernel 5.8.0-38-generic
I thought 20.10 was a better option due the the newer kernel looking at issues other people had
Used LVM with encryption

Results:
It took me like 3 attempts to be able to install the OS, the process failed both during and after the the OS install. I then tried to create the partitions beforehand and then was able to finish the install. I chose the minimal install, no update and no 3rd party stuff to make it quicker and I also though there was less chance of trying to install drivers that aren't supported, but looking at the installation details maybe the normal install would've been faster as I think it loaded everything from the normal install and then removed everything. Anyway now it works well so I'm not going to dig more into this.

The first few reboots I got and error with cups-browsed, but it stopped happening by itself after a few reboots.

Configure Gestures using this process: https://medium.com/@kaigo/mac-like-gestures-on-ubuntu-20-04-dell-xps-15-7ea6e3be7f76 and it works well

GPU seems to work well on Intel and NVidia profiles, but doesn't seem to switch properly when I set it to On-Demand - more investigation needed. As reference even though I'm not much of a gamer. I tried Rise of the Tomb Raider and hit 60-90 FPS at 1080p High settings.

I'm realizing that the screen max refresh rate seems to be 60 no matter which resolution I chose which is weird because I bought this to replace my XPS 9570 which had a refresh rate of 120 for 2k and under. I never thought to check that before buying it as I thought for sure it would have at least the same refresh rate as my 2 years old xps 15, especially considering the RTX GPU, maybe it's a config issue - more investigation needed

```
alex@alex-XPS-17-9700:~$ xrandr Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 32767 x 32767 DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) eDP-1-1 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 366mm x 229mm 3840x2400 59.99 + 48.00
3840x2160 60.00 60.01 59.98 59.97
3200x1800 59.96 59.94
2880x1620 59.96 59.97
2560x1600 59.99 59.97* 2560x1440 59.99 59.99 59.96 59.95
2048x1536 60.00
1920x1440 60.00
1856x1392 60.01
1792x1344 60.01
2048x1152 59.99 59.98 59.90 59.91
1920x1200 59.88 59.95
1920x1080 60.01 59.97 59.96 59.93
```

Sound does not work on speakers and headphone jack as I anticipated with what I read before buying it, works well on Bluetooth - Issue fixed using this process: https://km.kkrach.de/p_dell_xps_17_9700/ (however there's a typo in the commands, you're looking at sof-firmware-1.6-1 , not sof-firmware-1.6-2, also the wget command didn't work so I downloaded it straight from the website)

More to come as I go along... Cheers!

Comment: Looks like a useful contribution. However, please format according to the format of this site, i.e. ask a clear question, and then post the resolution as an answer - it is perfectly fine on this site to answer your own question.

Comment: for sound issues I used 21.04 with a 5.18 kernel - and then sound worked. You might also need to toggle sound off/on again in the bios for the michrophone to work. Sounds weird but worked for me. Other more recent kernels, sound did not work at all - tried up to 5.12. hth

Comment: @NeilMcGill guessing you meant 5.11.18 and not 5.18?

Comment: Oops: Here it is fully: Linux version 5.8.18-050818-generic (kernel@kathleen) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.35.1) #202011011237 SMP Sun Nov 1 12:40:15 
UTC 2020

Comment: The latest 5.13 kernel seems to work out of the box for sound. I say seems to, as 1 out of 3 boots, the microphone did not work.