# XPS 17 sound issue with 21.04

Tags: sound, xps, 21.04

So 2 days ago I got a popup to update from 20.10 to 21.04 and like a moron I proceeded to it even though I knew that my XPS 17 was sorta tricky to get everything to work with 20.10 to begin with as detailed in my previous post:
[How to install Ubuntu 20.10 on the new XPS 17 (9700)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308884/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-10-on-the-new-xps-17-9700)

In any case everything seems to work except for the sound again as it seems to be the case with other people as well but the method I used to make it work with 20.10 doesn't seem to work with 21.04.

That part now seemed useless because everything was already on my system:

```
git clone https://github.com/maaarghk/soundwire-dkms
cd soundwire-dkms
git checkout latest-sofproject
cd ..
sudo mv soundwire-dkms /usr/src/soundwire-1.4.0
sudo dkms add soundwire/1.4.0
sudo dkms build soundwire/1.4.0
sudo dkms install soundwire/1.4.0
```

As evidenced with this error message:
alex@alex-XPS-17-9700:~$ sudo dkms add soundwire/1.4.0

```
[sudo] password for alex: 
Error! DKMS tree already contains: soundwire-1.4.0
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
```

So then I went to the next section, using the latest version:

```
wget http://tardis.tiny-vps.com/aarm/packages/s/sof-firmware/sof-firmware-1.7-2-any.pkg.tar.xz
tar xf sof-firmware-1.7-2-any.pkg.tar.*
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof /usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof.bak
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg /usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg.bak
sudo cp -r usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof/sof /usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof
sudo cp -r usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof/sof-tplg-v1.6/ /usr/lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg
```

Then still no sound so I rebooted and yet nothing. I saw a few other posts that mentionned how to modify the kernel to make it work and I had a crack at it - using this guy's process:
https://www.bluebert.info/?p=521

But I dont think I'm doing it right as it ran for a good while and ended up giving me a bunch of error messages after this command:

```
make -j 16 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom KDEB_PKGVERSION=$(make kernelversion)-1
```

...

```
      GEN     .version
      CHK     include/generated/compile.h
      LD      vmlinux.o
      MODPOST vmlinux.symvers
      MODINFO modules.builtin.modinfo
      GEN     modules.builtin
    BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole (pahole) is not available
    Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux
    Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
    make[3]: *** [Makefile:1177: vmlinux] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [debian/rules:7: build-arch] Error 2
    dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary subprocess returned exit status 2
    make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.package:77: deb-pkg] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:1548: deb-pkg] Error 2
```

Ideally I'd avoid the kernel solution as I don't know much about kernel configurations if it's not already obvious -_-

Hopefully someone can help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my XPS laptop and I had the same error due to building a kernel.
I've fixed that error by using a method described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657707/btf-tmp-vmlinux-btf-pahole-pahole-is-not-available

P.S. unfortunately, I could not find any other solutions for fixing sound problem except building the kernel with a custom configuration.